# How can I attach event handler to emberJs select

Tags: ember.js, ember-select

I am new to EmberJs and I have added a select (combo box) like this:

```
 {{view Ember.Select 
          content = clientOptions }}
```

in controller I have added

```
App.MyController = Ember.Controller.extend({

  clientOptions : ['All Data','My Data'],
```

**Now I am not sure how to add the event handler. Please help.** Basically i want to add event handler and wants to know which value is selected by user.

I googled and looked at lot of links but none talks about event handling.

Answer (score 1):

As the example states in http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html, you should do

```
   {{view Ember.Select
   content=clientOptions
   selection=selectedClientOption}}
```

where selectedClientOption is updated once you select any option. Here is a jsbin : http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rupum/1/

hope this helps.